# Headers already sent on custom plugin (Export function)

Tags: plugin-development, headers

I've developed a plugin and have an export function that exports data from wordpress to csv.. the issue is that the "Header" statement is causing the "Headers already sent error".

I've checked through my code and there's no html or anything being sent before hand.

the error is coming from script-loader.php (output started at /home/test1/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php:1403)

I've looked at the core php and the section shows the following -

```
function _print_styles() {
global $compress_css;

$wp_styles = wp_styles();

$zip = $compress_css ? 1 : 0;
if ( $zip && defined('ENFORCE_GZIP') && ENFORCE_GZIP )
    $zip = 'gzip';

if ( $concat = trim( $wp_styles->concat, ', ' ) ) {
    $dir = $wp_styles->text_direction;
    $ver = $wp_styles->default_version;

    $concat = str_split( $concat, 128 );
    $concat = 'load%5B%5D=' . implode( '&load%5B%5D=', $concat );

    $href = $wp_styles->base_url . "/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c={$zip}&dir={$dir}&" . $concat . '&ver=' . $ver;
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . esc_attr($href) . "' type='text/css' media='all' />\n";

    if ( !empty($wp_styles->print_code) ) {
        echo "<style type='text/css'>\n";
        echo $wp_styles->print_code;
        echo "\n</style>\n";
    }
}

if ( !empty($wp_styles->print_html) )
    echo $wp_styles->print_html;
```

}

Specific line 1403 -

```
if ( !empty($wp_styles->print_html) )
    echo $wp_styles->print_html;
```

here is my function that specifically does the export.

```
function process_bulk_action()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cj_raffle_tickets'; // do not forget about tables prefix

    if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
        $ids = isset($_REQUEST['ticketid']) ? $_REQUEST['ticketid'] : array();
        if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);
        if (!empty($ids)) {
            $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE ticketid IN($ids)");
        }
    }
    if ('export' === $this->current_action()) {
            //csv_export();
            //ob_start();

        $output = '';                                           //Assigning the variable to store all future CSV file's data
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table_name . "");   //Displays all COLUMN NAMES under 'Field' column in records     returned

        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach($result as $row) {
                $output = $output . $row->Field . ",";
            }
            $output = substr($output, 0, -1);               //Removing the last separator, because thats how CSVs work
        }
        $output .= "\n";
        $ids = isset($_REQUEST['ticketid']) ? $_REQUEST['ticketid'] : array();
        if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            $values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name where ticketid IN ($ids)");       //This here
        }

        foreach ($values as $rowr) {
            $fields = array_values((array) $rowr);                  //Getting rid of the keys and using numeric array to get values
            $output .= implode(",", $fields);      //Generating string with field separator
            $output .= "\n";    //Yeah...
        }
        // Download the file        
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $filedir = $upload_dir['path'];
        $filename = 'ticketssold_' . time() . '.csv';
        if ( ! is_writable( $filedir ) ) {
            wp_die( "<p>Uploads directory is not writable, can't save the file </p>", 'Directory not writable' );
        }
        $handle = fopen( $filedir . '/' . $filename, 'w' );

        fwrite( $handle, $output );
        fclose( $handle );
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename );
        header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
        header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $filedir . '/' . $filename ) );
        flush();
        readfile( $filedir . '/' . $filename );
        exit;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this.. I've searched forum after forum trying everything from ob_clean to ob_start, ob_flush etc.

thanks
Craig.

Comment: WordPress Core is fine. Most probably you do some `echo` in your plugin code.

Comment: Can you include your source code when outputing csv? Probably you are sending csv file after some html have been already loaded. I would suggest to use `admin_hook` to send csv.

Comment: what is the use of this line in your code :- echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . esc_attr($href) . "' type='text/css' media='all' />\n";

Comment: hi  @motivast can you explain what you mean by using the admin_hook?

Comment: @motivast  plugin code added to original question

Comment: @CraigJohnstone look at my answer

Comment: @motivast replied

Answer (score 0):

You are probably executing your `process_bulk_action` function in template where some html and headers are already sent. You have to use `handle_bulk_actions-edit-post` hook to execute your code before any content is sent. This might look something like that:

```
function wpse_287406_register_export_option($bulk_actions) {

    $bulk_actions['export_csv'] = __( 'Export to CSV');

    return $bulk_actions;
}

add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'wpse_287406_register_export_option' );

function wpse_287406_export_csv( $redirect_to, $doaction, $post_ids ) {

    if ( $doaction !== 'export_csv' ) {

        return $redirect_to;
    }

    // Export CSV code

    $file = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/file.csv' );

    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv' );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
    header( 'Pragma: public' );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file) );

    readfile($file);

    exit;
}

add_action( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-post', 'wpse_287406_export_csv', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using the bulk_action hook so that the user can select items in bulk then click Export.. therefore I dont understand how I can use this bulk_action hook within and admin_init?

Comment: Actually for bulk operation there are better hooks e.g. `handle_bulk_actions-edit-post` I provided you full example.

Comment: I cant get this to work at all.. when I use your code and remove the call to my old function (process_bulk_action()) nothing happens when I click "Export" on the bulk action button

Comment: My code is adding "Export to CSV" option to "Bulk Actions" select in "All Posts" view. Choose this option and click "Apply". Remember to select some posts otherwise `handle_bulk_actions-edit-post` hook won't be executed. Also as you see I'm using fake `file.csv` file to make export. Create this file, fill with some data and place it in the same directory where you place script.

Comment: whats in the prepare_items() function.. there is where I call process_bulk_action.. should I remove this also?

Comment: I don't see any `prepare_items` function in your code and my code so I don't know what you are referring to.